# "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" error for only some users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get the Azure AD Groups a user in member of:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_id>/memberOf
```

For some users I am getting the requested information but for others I am getting this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "fd9345ee-ee2f-4dfb-b7e8-ca53d0c804d9",
            "date": "2019-07-03T15:50:25"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the token using Client ID + Client Secret.

The app has these privileges:

```
(Application) Groups.Read.All
(Application) Users.Read.All
```

As I am getting the groups for some members it seems this is not a lack of privileges at Azure app level.

Can you please help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Fix by Caiyi Ju: "Since you are using client credential flow, you need to grant `Directory.Read.All permission (application)`."

Comment: If you get the access token by using client credentials, you need to grant application type permission. If you get the access token by the login in user, you can try @Abraham Linkon's solution.

Comment: I'm getting the login using clientID and clientSecret. The app has Application Groups.Read.All and Application Users.Read.All.

With that permissions I'm able to get the groups a user is member of for some members, but not for all ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using client credential flow, you need to grant `Directory.Read.All` permission(application).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now the issue is fixed!

Answer (score 2):

You need `Directory.Read.All Delegated` permission You could [check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

See how you could do it.

[image]

`Delegated Directory.Read.All` Permission

[image]

After adding permission don't for get to click `Grant Consent`

[image]

**Post Man Test:**

[image]

Comment: I have tried but It is getting the same error about the lack of privileges. Do you have any more clue about this? Thanks!!

Comment: Finally it was Directory.Read.All Application permission. Thanks!